# send multiple ajax post requests at regular intervals until any one of them passed

Tags: javascript, php, es6-promise, request-promise, double-submit-problem

I am writing a test program for website most of time the website gives 504 error.
i want to write a program that can sent ajax requests to server and replace page with server response html.
the process of requests is like :

1. send 20 requests at a time if any of them got 200 response then cancell
   all other requests
2. repeat step 1 after 10 seconds until any request got valid response.

currently i am making 20 ajax calls and the wait for any of them to complete using Promise.any().
the problem i am facing is that how can i manage all batches in one Promise.any() because i need to keep track of previous batch as well like if one of second batch calls completed i need to cancell all first batch calls and remaining 2nd batch calls.
Hope you got my point what i want.
here is the code i have done so far

```
var reqs = [];
async function post_page(url, i){

    var formElement = document.getElementById('form1');
    var data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(formElement));
    data.append('continue', 'Continue');

    let controller = new AbortController();
    var req = fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
    }
     ).then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject('not ok');
        }
      return (response, i);
  });
    reqs.push(controller);
};

var load_page = function(url){
    var promises = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        promises.push(post_page(url, i));
    };

     Promise.any(promises).then((value, index) => {
         reqs.splice(index,1);
         $.each(reqs, function(id, req){req.abort();})
        loadPageHtml(value);
    })
};
```

Comment: you would need [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) I believe

Comment: lol - just read your code again and my comment was telling you to do exactly what you are doing - sorry